# Encrypt and Decrypt AES with Golang and Ruby

Tags: ruby, encryption, cryptography, go, aes

I'm working on making two secure systems talk via a common encryption scheme. I picked AES as it seems a secure standard, but I'm not married to it, so long as I have two way encryption.

Here is the [Go source](https://gist.github.com/thinkclay/9723296) and [Ruby source](https://gist.github.com/thinkclay/9723304) simplified down to a really clear example to run from command line and see the differences. I'm outputting bytecode for easier literal comparison.

I'm using 128 bit CFB in both, and neither of them appear to have padding, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please paste the relevant code inside your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed wrong key size in Ruby code. It should be 192. (because `key.size` is 24 bytes == 192 bits)

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(192, :CFB)
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = key
cipher.iv = iv
encrypted = cipher.update(input) + cipher.final()
puts "Output:     [" + encrypted.bytes.join(" ") + "]"
```

output:

```
Output:     [155 79 127 80 31 163 142 111 13 211 221 163 219 248]
```

Comment: Block size is not the same as key size. AES only supports 128-bit blocks.

Comment: @ntoskrnl, Ah, my fault. I misspelled `key size` as `block size`. Thank you for the comment. I updated the word according to your comment.